Low impedance rail to rail logic output implementation?
I understand that the true implementations on chips are proprietary, but lets say that I want to implement a logical inverter out of discrete parts. The common circuit that I see is something like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I suppose this could be inverted with a PNP transistor. The problem however, is while this provides very low impedance to one rail, it has the flaw of having R1 impedance to the other rail. If this is being used to drive a capacitive load, such as a MOSFET or even CMOS logic at high enough frequency, this becomes a big problem. However, this doesn't really seem to be an issue when using the outputs of a CMOS inverter IC. So how could we implement such a thing in discrete logic? I suppose we could extend it like this:

simulate this circuit
If we use small signal MOSFETS such as integrated CMOS logic, the gate capacitance would be rather small. However, we would still get a little bit of shoot-through current during transition, especially as the gate is charged through R1.
Is the answer here just that integrated CMOS logic inverters have a very carefully designed and balanced Pch to Nch output drive that, as the manufacturer has full control over the silicon, can be tuned to minimize the shoot-through current? Or is there a better way to do this out of discrete parts?

IC CMOS logic has no bipolar transistors.  All the transistors are MOSFETs.

If you want to invert a CMOS logic level with discrete components, all you need are the two FETs. Why include the BJTs that only complicate things?

@CarlRutschow BiCMOS exists as well. I don't know that the process was ever used for logic chips, but there was a period where a combination of CMOS and bipolar transistors on the same IC produced better performance. I've encountered it mostly in analog ICs--op amps and the like.

This is a design problem, like any other -- and so we must ask, what are we designing for, what are the requirements, what do we need to happen, and what do we need to avoid?
If you're doing something like building logic from discrete transistors, efficiency may be a huge concern.  You'll need thousands of transistors to build a computer, for example.
The biggest downside with commercial transistors is, they are huge.  The go-to jellybean 2N7002 is a whopping 30pF (between most terminals, give or take bias voltage) and handles 100s of mA and over 50V.  Which is huge power if you tried to do that continuously (5V 100mA is already at or beyond the rating of the SOT-23 package) and makes them essentially useless/inapplicable for RF applications.
What's relevant about RF?  Well, low capacitance means fast switching, and lower power dissipation in a CMOS circuit.  All the discrete RF MOSFETs are long dead and gone.  There used to be* parts like 3N170, with just a few pF capacitance, ratings around 10mA 30V, fairly high RDS(on), reasonable transconductance.  They don't exist, because there are too few applications for them; at all but the highest frequencies, RF is all on ICs now, with bleedingest-edge stuff occasionally needing a preamp, for which there are discrete parts with whopping fT in the 60GHz or more range; besides being expensive, needless to say you'll not even be able to notice such things oscillating in a circuit, let alone be able to control them with the help of conventional test equipment.
The other thing about efficiency is transfer function: what VGS and ID curve does it have, and how does this compare to VDD?  Because, if VGS(th) is relatively high, not much current (shoot-through) flows in the inbetween / transition range, but also not much current flows in general and minimum rise/fall time (say, after chaining a few inverters together, a maximum drive strength condition) isn't very good.  There's a tradeoff between shoot-through and speed.  This is more or less why modern CPUs run at low voltages, with transistors designed for minimal threshold voltage.
*I say "used to", but there is always some surplus around, and Linear Systems still makes a handful: https://www.linearsystems.com/mosfets However, the point stands: they are boutique items, low production, and priced accordingly; you wouldn't want to be using them for general logic applications.
There is one exception: CD4007 is a couple N and P-channel transistors, and unbuffered inverters, built in the ancient metal-gate CMOS process.  They don't perform very well, though: VGS(th) is high, RDS(on) is high, they don't match well to circuit impedances (say, trace transmission line Zo), so it might not draw much current but it won't go very fast either.
On the more practical side, you might use a discrete gate circuit to drive MOSFETs, in the rare case where an IC isn't acceptable (say, requiring lower quiescent current than available ICs).  You might use one or a few to drive output signals in a special application that isn't well served by ICs (say for odd voltages, at higher currents, etc.).  Perhaps even where you need a bit more power but not so much as a full driver or amplifier or whatever would need (say, where you'd otherwise use a bootstrap driver plus power transistors, but just need a fraction to a couple of watts, not worth the bother of all that).
The classics remain relevant, as they ever did since the '60s when discretes were all we had.
Note that BJTs are better for most of these, being available in smaller sizes than MOSFETs (a 2N3904 doesn't have much more active area than what a general transistor would have on a contemporary IC), transconductance is higher, and VBE is more convenient to work with.
MOSFETs would be better in most respects, if they were available in smaller sizes (yet somehow not an absolute pain to deal with in terms of ESD vulnerability) and matched VGS(th), but alas the variation is quite wide, making them mostly suitable as switches.  (On-chip matching makes them suitable in many analogous BJT circuits, and hence various powerful analog CMOS applications they're found in.)
A TTL-style output stage can be made with two or more transistors:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Q2 acts as an emitter follower, boosting R3's pull-up strength by hFE times, over most of the voltage range (minus a saturation voltage of VBE).  Q1 still needs to be driven pretty hard (it's sinking all load current through D1) so may not have much fan-in depending on requirements, and maybe you need another booster in front or something.  (Q1 is also a good place to use a MOSFET.)

simulate this circuit
A CMOS-style output stage can be made with some resistors, with base voltage fixed by divider (resistor divider at least, but diodes, or current mirroring with more transistors, improves temperature and design/manufacturing stability), and current limiting set by emitter degeneration.  This gives a nice square-ish operating area (V vs. I), with saturation voltage still near the rails (for light loads), minus the resistor voltage drop and a bit of VCE(sat).
I used such a circuit on a project a long time ago, along with ESD clamp diodes, and RC or LC (ferrite bead) filtering to set risetime and signal bandwidth; the resulting waveform is quite clean (well rounded, no crunchy wiggles or overshoot), and with protection, it's robust to any magnitude of ESD and EMI it'll ever see (or even surge, given suitable TVS).  Very belt-and-suspenders, but uses up a ton of components in the process.

simulate this circuit
We can make many tweaks to the basic CMOS circuit.  If VGS(th) is relatively low compared to VDD, we can avoid shoot-through by using less [AC] drive voltage, keeping VGS low and avoiding shoot-through.  Various biasing and level shifting schemes apply; the above simply shows a DC restore network (AC coupling, pull-up resistor, clamp diode), which would work for a consistent AC input below 100% duty cycle, and say 0/8V square wave, when VDD is 15V or more.  Note that VGS for the PMOS is the difference between IN and VDD so this is sensitive to supply ripple; have local bypass, and don't use on a "dirty" supply (more than, say, a volt of ripple, for parts like shown; less for logic-level types, I would say).
Splitting the signal path, we can delay high and low sides independently:

simulate this circuit
This way, VGS drive voltage can be higher (including full VDD, if within limits) without worry of shoot-through.  There is still a big pulse of current as one MOSFET charges the others' capacitance (when the load is small or capacitive), but this is the minimum shoot-through possible given such conditions.
Note that NOT3 has to be high-side referenced at its output, and potentially level-shifting by extension (GND-referenced input).  Literal CMOS gates are good when supplies are common (say 5V for 74HC, up to 15V for CD4000 -- deal with the weak drive capability by using a complementary emitter follower to boost it), else you'll have to do something else (ICs or otherwise).  Probably something more complicated (combining variations of the above, with level shifting, and by then perhaps you need UVLO, hysteresis and so on, and an IC looks very attractive indeed--) for any higher voltage, where you can't simply pull the gates to VDD/GND safely anymore.


...integrated CMOS logic inverters have a very carefully designed and
balanced Pch to Nch output drive...

Yes, output drive strength pulling up is roughly matched with drive strength pulling down for logic chips, by modifying PMOS & NMOS geometry.
Shoot-through is dependent on supply voltage Vdd. The manufacturer specifies a Vdd range over which shoot-through is deemed tolerable, but you'll often see a caution, "don't dally too long as you switch inputs from low-to-high, or high-to-low" (from Diodes inc. 74HCU04 data sheet):
Shoot-through current goes through a maximum peak as input voltage to the NMOS and PMOS gates passes through half-Vcc (roughly). To keep dissipation low, the only remedy offered is "don't dally".
For the two CMOS transistors in 74HCU04, shoot-through current is least bothersome at low Vdd supply voltage, and becomes less-tolerable at high Vdd. The NXP data sheet plots shoot-through current for three different Vdd's:

Vdd 2V.....shoot-thru peaks at 0.5mA
Vdd 4.5V...shoot-thru peaks at 12mA
Vdd 6.0V...shoot-thru peaks at 24mA !

The shoot-thru peak at Vdd=6V is rather broad. One would want to transition through half-Vdd very quickly.
I'm using 74HCU04 example CMOS because it matches closely OP's diagram.
The 4000 series CMOS gates have a wider supply range (3V - 18V) but have PMOS and NMOS transistors with less drive strength. I believe shoot-through current is still a problem with 4049 inverters...the "don't dally" caution is similarly suggested, indirectly. The shoot-through problem seems to be one we are expected to put up with.
A relevant Texas Instruments document SCBA004E addresses issues of oscillation in the transition region and a few other quirky issues and tricks too.

The EDP Wasp musical synthesizer (ab)uses CD4069 inverters as op-amps in its filter circuit; the Wasp and modern clones of its filter are well-known for occasionally self-destructing the inverters. A sawtooth or triangle oscillator running at 100-1000Hz would be about 3 orders of magnitude out of that dalliance spec?

You can assist the collector resistor with another transistor:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left Q2 boosts current needed to raise output potential. Slew rate is hindered by parasitic capacitance C1, the main cause of performance degradation when using a simple pull-up resistor. By increasing the amount of current available to charge C1, rise time is reduced dramatically, which can be seen in this comparison between the "boosted" circuit on the left (orange) and the simple pull-up resistor design on the right (brown):

Of far greater concern is the time it takes for Q1 to recover from saturation, which results in the delay between input falling edge (blue) and the beginning of the rise of the output (orange). In TTL ICs this is mitigated by connecting a schottkey diode between base and collector. You could also employ emitter degeneration with a resistor (R3 below) to keep Q1 out of saturation:

simulate this circuit

The caveat is that the input signal needs to be constrained to 1V or so maximum, which is inconvenient, but you at least see how recovery time is reduced, and how saturation is just as problematic (if not more so) than rise time constraints imposed by a simple pull-up resistor.
